# Accessing classes in .a library file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How do I access any classes in a library when all I have is the .a file?  I've included the -ObjC linker flag and added the .a file to my project.  Still, none of the classes appear in code hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean Code Sense/autocompletion, IIRC they're based off of included headers. If you don't have the headers, you won't get the hints.

Comment: I see.  I tried a method on a static class but it says the class is undeclared.

Comment: Was it a linker error, or a compiler error? If it was the latter, can declare the class and its methods yourself (e.g., in your own separate header file).

Comment: Including the header works.  So, in order to use the .a file, you must include its header files?  It isn't self contained?  I see you can also step through the code in the .a file as well.

Comment: Yes, headers are needed for static libraries as they are for frameworks.  Unfortunately, we can't bundle headers with the libraries like we can with frameworks, so they need to be provided separately.